# SQL SELECT "pair" records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are cities, suppliers, and customers tables.

Each `supplier`, (as well as `customer`), is located in one and only one city.

```
CREATE TABLE Cities (
    Id int IdENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE Suppliers (
    Id int IdENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    CityId int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Suppliers_Cities FOREIGN KEY (CityId)
        REFERENCES Cities (CityId)
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
    Id int IdENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    CityId int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Customers_Cities FOREIGN KEY (CityId)
        REFERENCES Cities (CityId)
```

How could I select pairs of supplier and customer within the city, where each of them is mentioned only once?
P.S. if there is no "pair" `NULL` should be instead. E.g.:

| cityId | supplierId | customerId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | NULL |
| 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | NULL | 4 |

So... having suppliers with ids `1`, `2` are located in city `1` and customers with ids `1`, `2` are located there as well:

With `JOIN` I receive "duplicated" pairs (e.g. 1-1, 1-2, 2-1, 2-2), here I ask how to make (1-1, 2-2) pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want vertical lists of suppliers and customers.  The problem is that you don't have a `join` key.  You can create one with `row_number()`:

```
select coalesce(s.cityid, c.cityid) as cityid,
       s.id as supplierid, c.id as customerid
from (select s.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from suppliers s
     ) s full join
     (select c.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from customers c
     ) c
     on s.cityid = c.cityid and s.seqnum = c.seqnum
order by cityid, coalesce(s.seqnum, c.seqnum)
```